# Regex - add new field between semicolon separators - notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have data like this (some of the fields have values, some of them don't)

```
J;555;3;1990-02-19;1234;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE
```

I need to add a new field right before the 5th semicolon, like this (the F value):

```
J;555;3;1990-02-19;1234;F;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE
```

So far I have this:

```
^(([A-Z]);([0-9A-Z]+);([?:0-9]);([0-9\-]+);([A-Z0-9]+));(.*)$
```

And as replacement:

```
$1;$2;F;$7
```

As far as I know the ?: before is to mark optional, but in my case I need to represent empty fields between every semicolon

How can I solve this?

Comment: Record a macro.  start at the beginning of a line, start recording, find semicolon 5 times, insert F, jump to the start of the line and move down one line.  end macro and playback as needed for the rest of the file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make groups optional? https://regex101.com/r/yOp5SJ/1?

Comment: *"As far as I know the `?:` before is to mark optional"*: no it isn't: `?:` sequence is used in combination with parenthesis to say that a group is not a capture group: `(?: ... )`

Comment: Additionally, the way you've used it `([?:0-9])` means `?` and `:` will be matched literally.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /^([A-Z]);([0-9]*);([0-9]*);([0-9-]*);([0-9]*);(.*)$/


let str = 'J;555;3;1990-02-19;1234;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE'
str = str.replace(regex, '$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;F;$6')
let expected = 'J;555;3;1990-02-19;1234;F;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE'
console.log(str === expected)

str = 'J;;3;1990-02-19;;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE'
str = str.replace(regex, '$1;$2;$3;$4;$5;F;$6')
expected = 'J;;3;1990-02-19;;F;S;2020-10-17;;;;;value;3;ANOTHERVALUE'
console.log(str === expected)
```

You can find an explanation on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tqjkpl/1)

Basically, I made use of `*` which matches from zero to unlimited times to account for instances with missing values.

```
^([A-Z]);([0-9]*);([0-9]*);([0-9-]*);([0-9]*);(.*)$
```

**Description**

- `([A-Z])` Match any `A-Z` character
- `;` Matches a semi-colon literally
- `([0-9]*)` Match any number between zero and unlimited times
- `;` Matches a semi-colon literally
- `([0-9]*)` Match any number between zero and unlimited times
- `;` Matches a semi-colon literally
- `([0-9]*)` Match any number between zero and unlimited times
- `;` Matches a semi-colon literally
- `([0-9]*)` Match any number between zero and unlimited times
- `;` Matches a semi-colon literally
- `(.*)` Matches any character between zero and unlimited times

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code in notepad++,

Find:`^((.*?;){5})`
Replace with:`$1F;`

[image]